# Append numpy array with diff dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I do this? I just need a numpy array/dictionary of the form

```
[ z (an int), [lamda (np float array)], [flux (np float array)] ]
```

So I can create the 'data25' numpy array below... But when I try to append another record with the same format, I get an error:

```
data25 = [0.0,sData1['lambda'],sData1['flux']]
print data25
for z in np.arange(0.2,1.0,0.2):
    newLambdaArr = []
    newFluxArr   = []
    for entry in sData1:
        newLambdaArr = np.append(newLambdaArr, [entry[0] * (1.0 + z)])
        newFluxArr   = np.append(newFluxArr,   [entry[1]/(fpi * frw.dl(z) * (1+z))])
    print 'new lambda',newLambdaArr
    print 'new flux', newFluxArr
    temp = [z, newLambdaArr, newFluxArr]
    print 'just built: ', temp
    data25 =  np.append(data25, [temp] )
    print data25
```

I get the error at the "data25 = np.append..." line:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The first "print data25" gives me what I want:

```
[0.0, array([  9.10000000e+01,   9.40000000e+01,   9.60000000e+01, ...,
     1.20000000e+06,   1.40000000e+06,   1.60000000e+06], dtype=float32), array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
     3.60900003e-08,   1.95199998e-08,   1.14600001e-08], dtype=float32)]
```

Thx

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  Use `alist.append(newvalue)`.  If you want `numpy` arrays (as opposed to Python lists), create those explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.append` works differently, it'll return a single list with the elements inside the list you have as argument so it's not what you want:

```
>>> np.append([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Your use case can be done with a simple Python list like this:

```
>>> z = 5
>>> flux = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> lambdas = np.array([4, 5, 6])
>>> data = [z, flux, lambdas]
>>> data
[5, array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
# Alternatively you can do data.append(z), data.append(flux) and then data.append(lambdas)
```

If you want the result to be a numpy array, you'll have to shape it like a multidimensional array:

```
>>> data = np.array([np.array([z]), flux, lambdas]) # Notice the z integer is passed as an array
>>> data
array([array([5]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

If you don't shape it like that, you'll get your error:

```
>>> data = np.array([z, flux, lambdas])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Thanks... That: `data = np.array([np.array([z]), flux, lambdas])` works perfectly.